# What's the equivalent Java implementation of this C# generic method pattern

Tags: java, c#, generics, lambda

I am re writing a library originally written in C# into Java and am trying my best to follow it as closely as possible. This, however, has me stumped.

This is the C# method I want to recreate in Java

```
public T With<TV>(Func<T, IEditable> func, TV value)
        {
            var pageElement = func(TypedThis);
            pageActions.Add(new WebDriverValuePageAction<TV>(pageElement, value));
            return TypedThis;
        }
```

This is a generic method which is used as part of a Selenium Page Object framework where T is a BasePage and the Method takes any page element inheriting the IEditable interface.

What is stumping me is the `With<TV>` part of the method and how to recreate this in Java. Everything else is pretty much done. I have been able to recreate **T** but cannot work out how to also pass in TV (essentially a generic value) along with the function.

Comment: `<TV>` just introduces a second generic type parameter for this method, there is already `T` which is presumable a type parameter on the class level + the `TV` on method level. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: What's `TypedThis`?

Comment: TypedThis = this as T;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct equivalent will be

```
    public <TV> T With(Function<T, IEditable> func, TV value)
    {
        IEditable pageElement = func.apply(TypedThis);
        pageActions.Add(new WebDriverValuePageAction<TV>(pageElement, value));
        return TypedThis;
    }
```

Comment: Excellent thanks for this. C# and Java are so similar but these little minor differences keep stumping me

Comment: @Phonesis Yes. Keep in mind that generics work different in Java and C#. You better read something about it.